# GCP Data Prep AVRO file doesn't reflect schema in Data Prep. Datetime field changed to string field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, avro, google-cloud-dataprep

I am using Google Cloud Platforms (GCP) Data Prep (DP) to move data into Big Query (BQ) via AVRO files. I am taking the data straight from a CSV file to a AVRO file using one DP recipe with NO transformations. In DP the type of my column `CreatedDate` is `date/time` as seen in this picture:

[image]

NOTE: The year (in the format YYYY-) is painted out.

When I publish the the data into a AVRO file using these settings:

[image]

The resulting AVRO schema looks like this in plain text:

`{"name":"CreatedDate","type":["null","string"],"default":null}`

And when imported into BQ is also a column of type `string`

However, if I publish the data straight to BQ using the `Replace-BigQuery` publish option in DP the`CreatedDate` column will be of type `DATETIME` and be `NULLABLE` which is exactly what I want.

I looked around and could not find any know issues publishing from DP to an AVRO file that would make datetime fields into string fields.

Did I miss anything?

Does AVRO not support datetime or datetime in this format like BQ does?

Yes I need to have DP publish to a AVRO file. I just did the direct publish to BQ as a test. I can not do this for the long term.

Any other suggestions/help would be wonderful!

Comment: Can you just load directly into BigQuery instead? Dataprep has limited type support compared to BigQuery.

Comment: No. In this example I am not doing an transforms, but in the future I will be doing quite a few.

Comment: You could consider using Dataflow directly instead, then, in conjunction with the BigQuery sink. Dataprep runs Dataflow jobs behind the scenes.

Comment: The reason I am using DP is to make a lot 100+ recipes to normalize some data very quickly using a UI.